# How to compute this gross limit.

Tags: limits

> How do I compute this limit?
>   $$
>   \lim_{n \to \infty} 
>   \frac{\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n - 
>         \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n
>   }{
>        2 \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n - 
>         \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2 + 1}\right)^n - 
>         \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2 (n^2 +1)}\right)^n
>   }
> $$

I think I got the correct limit by using fast converging limits to $e$.
In particular I used truncated Taylor series for the sqrt and 4th root.
Or squares and bisquares.

Example

$(1+1/2n)^{2n}$
 Becomes 
$(1 + 1/n + 1/4n^2)^n.$

In combination with l'hopital it gives me the answer.

But I guess that is not a very good (fast) method.

Comment: what are your thoughts?

Comment: Close votes ? Really ?

Comment: probably you have in the denominator a $   2( 1+ \frac{1}{n}+ \frac{1}{n^2} )^n  $, otherwise the answers solve you this problem

Comment: Thanks Clark !! A typo sorry.

Comment: I fail to see how this is " off topic " :/ Imho too many close votes these days ... Or is it just me ?

Comment: *Taylor formula at order $1$* on the function $f_n(x)=(1+1/n+x)^n$ yields readily, using the shorthands $a=f_n(0)\in\Theta(1)$ and $b=f'_n(0)\in\Theta(n)$, that the ratio is $$\frac{a+b/n^2-(a-b/n^2)+o(1/n)}{2(a+b/n^2)-(a-b/n^2)-a+o(1/n)}=\frac{2b/n^2+o(1/n)}{3b/n^2+o(1/n^2)}\to\frac23.$$ Note that exact asymptotics of $a$ and $b$, not to mention the exact limit of $a$, are irrelevant.

Comment: @Did In case you saw it, I just wrote you a comment about your post: I deleted my  comment, because you were right, and I was wrong... sigh

Answer (score 2):

Hint: First show $(1+1/n +o(1/n))^n \to e.$

Comment: I could do that with taylor or with l'hopital. But how does that help " much " here ?

Comment: Suppose you know this. What is the limit of the numerator? What is the limit of the denominator?

Comment: Sorry , I made a typo !

Comment: Well with the new version, I'm not sure "gross" is the right term. Perhaps "perverse"? (Maybe there's a nice way to see it. Sorry, but I have to clean the lint trap now.)

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $a^n-b^n = (a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$. It is going to be quite lengthy so bear with me: The numerator is
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n-
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n = \frac{2}{n^2}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n-1-m}
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^m
$$
Write the above as $2/n^2 f(n)$.
The denominator has two parts
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n-
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2+1}\right)^n = \left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^2+1}\right)g(n)
$$
where
$$g(n) = \sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n-1+m}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2+1}\right)^m$$
and the second part
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n-
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2(n^2+1)}\right)^n = \frac{1}{n^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+1}\right)k(n)
$$
where
$$k(n)=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n-1+m}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2(n^2+1)}\right)^m$$
so in the end you have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{2}{n^2}f(n)}{\frac{2n^2+1}{n^2(n^2+1)}g(n)+\frac{n^2+2}{n^2(n^2+1)}h(n)}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2(n^2+1)f(n)}{(2n^2+1)g(n)+(n^2+2)h(n)}
$$
Now note that as $n\to \infty$ then $f(n)$ becomes approximately
$$f(n) = \sum_{m=0}^{n-1}
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n-1-m}
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^m\approx n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\approx ne$$
where $\approx$ means to order of $o(1)$. Actually $g(n)\approx ne\approx h(n)$ too.
 So the limit reduces to
$$\to \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2(n^2+1)}{(2n^2+1)+(n^2+2)}=\frac{2}{3}$$
Hopefully I haven't made a mistake anywhere, but at least I think the method is clear.

Comment: I don't immediately see why the errors in your computation of $f(n)$ are only $o(1/n)$, but you only need them to be $o(n)$, which is easy to see because each of the $n$ terms is converging to $e$ and this convergence is uniform across all the terms.

Comment: You're completely right. Actually I was just thinking about that myself. The order is definitely not $o(1/n)$, at most it is $o(1)$ (I'm not sure about this either). But as you just said $o(n)$ is enough.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a  way to 'see the answer' is to use the MVT: for the numerator, write $f( x) = x^n$, $a = 1 + 1/n -1/n^2$, $b = 1 + 1/n + 1/n^2$. Then 
$$ f( b) - f(a) = f'(c)(b-a),$$
for some $c \in (a,b)$.
 Therefore the numerator is
$$ n\left(1 + 1/n + o(1/n^2)\right)^{n-1} 2/n^2.$$
Similarly, in the denominator, using the same trick twice, one gets
$$ n\left(1 +1/n + o(1/n^2)\right)^{n-1} ( 2/n^2 + 1/(n^2+1) + 1/n^2(n^2+1) ).$$
Taking the limit (of the ratio!), one gets Hamed's answer of $2/3$.

Comment: @Hamed just to confirm your answer of 2/3...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** (for the first version, before multiplying by 2)
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\leq\left(1+\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}\right)^n\leq\left(1+\frac{1+\epsilon}n\right)^n
$$
for large $n$. Hence all partial limits are $e$ and the final one — 0.

Comment: Not trying to be rude but : so what ? Far from a solution ?

Comment: @mick The limit of the second term is between $e$ and $e^{1+\epsilon}$, hence is equal to $e$. You can show in the similar way, that the other limits of expressions of the form $(...)^n$ are also $e$.

Comment: Yes.  But I made a typo. Sorry.

Comment: Perhaps better to use $$(1+1/n+c/n^2)^n=\exp(n·\ln(1+1/n+c/n^2))\\=\exp(n·((1/n+c/n^2)-(1/n+c/n^2)^2/2+O(1/n^3)))\\=e·(1+(c-1/2)/n+O(n^2))$$ to get a better quantification of the error.

Answer (score 0):

You might get some easy simplifications by extending the fraction with the factor $(1-\frac1n)^n$ so that all terms transform to the form
$$
\left(1+\frac{c_n}{n^2}\right)^n=1+\frac{c_n}{n}+O(n^{-2}).
$$
to obtain
\begin{align}
&\ \lim_{n \to \infty} 
  \frac{\left(1  - \frac{1}{n^3}\right)^n - 
        \left(1  - \frac{2}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^3}\right)^n
  }{
       2 \left(1 - \frac{1}{n^3}\right)^n - 
        \left(1 - \frac{2n^2+1-n}{n^2 (n^2 + 1)}\right)^n - 
        \left(1 - \frac{n^2+2}{n^2 (n^2+1)} + \frac{1}{n^3 (n^2 +1)}\right)^n
  }
\\ \\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} 
  \frac{\left(1 + O(n^{-2})\right) - 
       \left(1-\frac2n +  O(n^{-2}) \right)
  }{
       2 \left(1 +  O(n^{-2})\right) - 
        \left(1 - \frac{2}{n} + O(n^{-2})\right) - 
        \left(1 - \frac{1}{n} + O(n^{-2})\right)
  }
\\ \\
&=\frac 23
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$
n\log\left(1+\frac1n+\frac{x}{n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)=1+\frac xn-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left(1+\frac1n+\frac{x}{n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)^n=e\left(1+\frac xn-\frac1{2n}\right)+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)
$$
Thus
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{\overbrace{\left(1+\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}\right)^n}^{x=1}-\overbrace{\left(1+\frac1n-\frac1{n^2}\right)^n}^{x=-1}}{2\underbrace{\left(1+\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}\right)^n}_{x=1}-\underbrace{\left(1+\frac1n-\frac1{n^2+1}\right)^n}_{x=-1}-\underbrace{\left(1+\frac1n-\frac1{n^2(n^2+1)}\right)^n}_{x=0}}\\
&=\frac{e\left(1+\frac1n-\frac1{2n}\right)-e\left(1-\frac1n-\frac1{2n}\right)+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)}{2e\left(1+\frac1n-\frac1{2n}\right)-e\left(1-\frac1n-\frac1{2n}\right)-e\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\frac2n+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)}{\frac3n+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)}
\end{align}
$$